Very strange warning by gcc and clang
Given the following code:
#define MAX(a,b) \
   ({ __typeof__ (a) _a = (a); \
       __typeof__ (b) _b = (b); \
     _a > _b ? _a : _b; })

int main() {
  short int a=1,b=2;
  a=MAX(a,b);
  return 0;
}

gcc -Wconversion gives the following warning:
toto.c: In function ‘main’:
toto.c:2:4: warning: conversion from ‘int’ to ‘short int’ may change value [-Wconversion]
    2 |    ({ __typeof__ (a) _a = (a); \
      |    ^
toto.c:8:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘MAX’
    8 |   a=MAX(a,b);

Does anybody know why? Eveything is a short int from start to end.

This is because when you use values of a type smaller than int in an expression, it will undergo arithmetic conversion, which leads to the values being promoted to int.

Well if I write directly a=a>b ?a : b; there is no warning... So why is it not promoted here, and promoted in the macro?

So no, not everything in that code is short int.  But the diagnostic itself is a false alarm, based on data types alone.  The code presented will not, in fact, ever attempt to store an out-of-range value in a short int.

_a > _b ? _a : _b has type int when _a and _b have type short. Hurray for C!

As a side note you are nowadays able to use the typeof operator without the __ since it is introduced in standard C with the upcoming C23.

See 6.5.13 Conditional operator, where it says (¶5): If both the second and third operands have arithmetic type, the result type that would be determined by the usual arithmetic conversions, were they applied to those two operands, is the type of the result. If both the operands have structure or union type, the result has that type. If both operands have void type, the result has void type.

First of all, -Wconversion isn't really trustworthy and prone to so-called false positives = warnings for things that aren't actual problems. You shouldn't keep it on permanently, only temporary during code review etc.
In this case there is indeed an implicit conversion from int to short int but the compiler fails to recognize that the int originates from a promoted short and so the conversion is harmless.
Specifically, the ?: is an oddball operator since it implicitly promotes the 2nd and 3rd operand against each other as if they were operands of a binary operation, even though only one of them is evaluated. Promotion is done through the usual arithmetic conversions which in turn integer promotes each operand, see Implicit type promotion rules.
In this case it means that _a > _b ? _a : _b;  is implicitly promoted according to _a > _b ? (int)_a : (int)_b; since short is a small integer type. The result of ?: is of type int and so that's also the type returned from the GNU ({ }) macro.
The conversion from int to short happens on the caller side a=MAX(a,b) since a is short.
You should be able to hush up -Wconversion with
(short)(_a > _b ? _a : _b)

but it is better to turn off that option entirely.

The strange thing is if I write directly a=a>b?a:b; there is no warning...

@james_elliot_62 It probably has something to do with the GNU-style macro which has to store a temporary return variable and that one is essentially treated as the return value from a function. If you replace the macro with a function returning int, you'll probably get the same warning.

There's a simple workaround: assign the result of the conditional to _a (or _b): #define MAX(a,b) ({ __typeof__ (a) _a = (a); __typeof__ (b) _b = (b); _a = (_a > _b) ? _a : _b; }) — and it probably doesn't affect the generated code at all.
